# SSH tunnel stops working after EC2 instance restart

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I have an SSH tunnel from an EC2 instance (say A) to another with an Elastic IP (say B). It worked perfectly. Yet, B had a failure. So I had to stop it, and start a new instance with the same Elastic IP. And now the exact same SSH tunnel does not work anymore. Yet:

- I can still SSH from A to B. So I know my keys are in place
- I tried the exact same tunnel from another instance than A, and it works as expected.

So somehow, it is as if A detected a problem when B went down, and it is now blocking the traffic.

Tunnel:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path_to/id_dsa -f -p 22 -N -L 26:www.foo.com:80 ssh_tunnel@amazon_public_ip
```

And when I try Curl here is what I get:

```
    curl -v -H "Host: www.foo.com" http://localhost:26/foofoo
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 26 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 26: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 26: Connection refused
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: One you start the tunnel, does it show that port 26 is in listening mode in the command output of `netstat -anp | grep ssh` ? For me, the message `connect to 127.0.0.1 port 26 failed: Connection refused` is quite straight forward.

Comment: Thanks @slayedbylucifer. Found the answer. Posting it below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I did not pay attention, but when I was SSH-ing into the instance, I was getting a warning message: `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`. Since it worked anyway, I thought it was not a problem. It turns out it makes the tunnel fail.

So I just removed the offending RSA key from known_hosts and now it works.